# Linq - Busca de objetos que possuem um lista pré-determinada

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Tenho uma entidade de many-to-many, muitos alunos para muitas matérias. E preciso pegar todos os alunos que possuem todas as matérias que eu desejo.

Por exemplo, matérias: Matemática, Português e Física. Preciso pegar apenas os alunos que possuem estas três matérias. Se ele possuir outra matéria, mas, possui estas três, tudo bem. Se ele possui apenas uma ou duas das matérias em questão, desconsiderar, não serve.

Minha tabela de relacionamento é a seguinte:

```
tbAlunosMaterias
AlunoId
MateriaId
```

É possível obter esta informação através de linq ou lambda? Alguma coisa do tipo:

```
var alunosDasMaterias = alunos.Contains(x => ... );
```

Onde: alunos = lista de todos os alunos com suas respectivas matérias
      (x) = onde eu informo a lista de matérias que o aluno deve possuir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa ter mapeada a associação entre Alunos e Matérias no seu contexto:

```
public DbSet<AlunoMateria> AlunosMaterias { get; set; }
```

A sentença ficaria assim:

```
var idsDasMaterias = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // Não sei quais são os Ids, então estou chutando Ids para as matérias
var alunosDasMaterias = contexto.AlunosMaterias
                                .Where(am => idsDasMaterias.Contains(am.MateriaId))
                                .Select(am => am.Aluno)
                                .ToList();
```